# Qual a diferença entre UNIQUE e PRIMARY KEY no Oracle?

Tags: banco-de-dados

Gostaria de saber qual a diferença entre `UNIQUE` e `PRIMARY KEY` no *Oracle*, sendo que `UNIQUE` define valores que não podem ser repetir, e a `PRIMARY KEY` em tese faz a mesma coisa.

Comment: `UNIQUE` quer dizer que o atributo não haverá repetição, até ai parece uma PK, mas por exemplo, eu tenho uma tabela onde CNPJ "seria" PK, só que não, pois existe empresas com o mesmo cnpj mas com inscrição estadual diferente, esse campo i.e seria unique, mas se não necessariamente a PK seria esse campo

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`PRIMARY KEY` define qual é a chave primária da tabela. Ou seja, qual é o conjunto de colunas que deve identificar uma tupla de forma única e não-ambígua. Além disso, a tabela costuma ser organizada internamente de acordo com a forma como a chave primária é definida. Além disso, o que é exportado para outras tabelas como chave estrangeira é a chave primária.

Entretanto, pode haver mais do que um jeito de se identificar uma tupla de forma única, e é aí que o `UNIQUE` entra.

Por exemplo, vamos supor que uma tabela `usuario` tenha os seguintes campos: nome, id, CPF, RG, e-mail e data de nascimento.

Vejamos, o id seria a chave primária. Entretanto, não podemos ter dois usuários com o mesmo e-mail, então o e-mail é `UNIQUE`. Também não podemos ter dois usuários com o mesmo RG ou o mesmo CPF, que são `UNIQUE` também.

Além disso, de vez em quando uma pessoa pode trocar de RG. Se o RG fosse a chave primária, você teria que sair cascateando as alterações em todas as chaves estrangeiras, problema esse que não existe em colunas `UNIQUE` que não sejam `PRIMARY KEY`.

Uma outra diferença, é que colunas `UNIQUE` podem ser `NULL`, enquanto que colunas `PRIMARY KEY`, não podem. Por exemplo, nesse caso que dei acima, isso seria útil se você for cadastrar um estrangeiro que não tem CPF e nem RG. Se um desses fosse chave primária, você iria se ferrar.

Comment: Resposta muito boa.

Comment: Muito obrigado pela ajuda Victor.

Answer (score 2):

Como o dito [nesse link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9565996/difference-between-primary-key-and-unique-key) do SOEN

**A chave primaria:**

- Pode existir apenas uma por *table*
- No Oracle não pode ser *NULL*
- É unica e é o principal meio de relacionar as *tables* desejadas.

**A chave Unica:**

- Pode existir mais do que uma em uma *table*
- Pode receber valores *NULL*
- Como pode ser *NULL* ela pode não ser "unica"

Além disso o uso das chaves primarias e estrangeiras garantes, garantem a conformidade e integridade dos dados e da estrutura das *tables*
EX: Você não pode deletar uma *table* ou um dado que seja dependente de outra, o que impede uma eventual inconformidade.

Comment: `unique` pode sim existir mais de um atributo desse tipo por tabela, mas não pode existir mais de um registro com o mesmo valor ... é justamente por isso que se chama assim

Comment: @SneepSNinjA O valor NULL pode se repetir

Comment: o conceito de NULL é inexistência de valor, então não existe "valor" NULL(prova disso você não pode fazer um `select * from tab where atributo=null`, por esse motivo uma PK não pode ser NULL, pois PK tem a obrigação de ter um "valor" logo não pode ser NULL

Comment: o que eu quero dizer é que a resposta não esta errada, só faltou argumentar o porque o `unique` permite null, e não permite "valores" repetidos

Answer (score 1):

`Primary Key`:

- Só pode existir um numa tabela
- `Primary Key` é um identificador exclusivo de um registro numa tabela

`Unique Key`:

- São unicas por registro da tabela
- Podem existir mais de uma `Unike Key` em uma tabela
- Permitem valores nulos
- É um candidato a se tornar uma `Primary Key`
- Uma `Unique Key` pode ser nula e ,no caso de nula, não exclusiva para o registro

fonte: https://stackoverflow.com/a/13349176/4166090

Comment: `unique` pode sim existir mais de um atributo desse tipo por tabela, mas não pode existir mais de um registro com o mesmo valor ... é justamente por isso que se chama assim...rsrsrsr

Comment: @SneepSNinjA isso mesmo, me espresei mal